# pyspark type error on reading a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I read some CSV file into pandas, nicely preprocessed it and set dtypes to desired values of float, int, category. However, when trying to import it into spark I get the following error:

```
Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>
```

After trying to trace it for a while I some source for my troubles -> see the CSV file:

```
"myColumns"
""
"A"
```

Red into pandas like: `small = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser('myCsv.csv'))`

And failing to import it to spark with:

```
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(small)
```

Currently I use Spark 2.0.0

#### Possibly multiple columns are affected. How can I deal with this problem?

[image]

Comment: I confirmed that this issue persists in 2.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to define the spark `DataFrame` schema explicitly and pass it to the `createDataFrame` function :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pandas as pd

small = pdf.read_csv("data.csv")
small.head()
#  myColumns
# 0       NaN
# 1         A
sch = StructType([StructField("myColumns", StringType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(small, sch)
df.show()
# +---------+
# |myColumns|
# +---------+
# |      NaN|
# |        A|
# +---------+

df.printSchema()
# root
# |-- myColumns: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: so it is not inferred from the pandas dtypes? :( I see.

Comment: could not finally confirm this yet --> there are several fields affected. But your code snippet works for the minimal example.

Comment: then why don't you read the csv using the spark-csv package ?

Comment: Good question. I cleaned the raw data in python and thought this would be easier. When I tried to read the data in spark there were some problems initially (with the raw data). What was strange for me when I used DataSets in scala to load the data all the columns were loaded anyways - even if I tried to exclude some problematic ones by not specifying it as an attribute in the case class.

The fixed data loads fine into spark, but trying to perform a conversion to parquet like `mynewDf.write.parquet("myDf.parquet")` errors.

Comment: I thought that this error was caused by a wrong dtype interpretation and wanted to read the data correctly via pandas.
But in the long run everything (especially the pandas preprocessing) should move to scala / spark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125073/discussion-between-eliasah-and-georg-heiler).