# TypeError: field Customer: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'>

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-arrow

```
SL No:  Customer    Month   Amount
1   A1  12-Jan-04   495414.75
2   A1  3-Jan-04    245899.02
3   A1  15-Jan-04   259490.06
```

My Df is above

Code

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/mak/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7')
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('mak').getOrCreate()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

pdf3 = pd.read_csv('Repayment.csv')
df_repay = spark.createDataFrame(pdf3)
```

only loading `df_repay` is having issue, other data frame are loaded successfully. When i shfted my above to code to below code its worked successfully

`df4 = (spark.read.format("csv").options(header="true")
    .load("Repayment.csv"))`

- why df_repay is not loaded with `spark.createDataFrame(pdf3)` while similar data frames loaded successfully

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyspark type error on reading a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888188/pyspark-type-error-on-reading-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pdf3 is pandas dataframe and you are trying to convert pandas dataframe to spark dataframe. if you want to stick to your code please use below code that is convert your pandas dataframe to spark dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
pdf3 = pd.read_csv('Repayment.csv')
#create schema for your dataframe
schema = StructType([StructField("Customer", StringType(), True)\
                   ,StructField("Month", DateType(), True)\
                   ,StructField("Amount", IntegerType(), True)])

#create spark dataframe using schema
df_repay = spark.createDataFrame(pdf3,schema=schema)
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. I would add the import statement as well, for completeness: ```from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DateType, IntegerType```