# PySpark MapType from column values to array of column name

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, melt

I've got a dataframe of `roles` and the `ids` of people who play those roles. In the table below, the roles are `a,b,c,d` and the people are `a3,36,79,38`.

What I want is a map of people to an array of their roles, as shown to the right of the table.

```
+---+----+----+---+---+--------+
|rec|   a|   b|  c|  d|    ppl |  pplmap
+---+----+----+---+---+--------+-------------------------------------
|  D|  a3|  36| 36| 36|[a3, 36]| [ a3 -> ['a'], 36 -> ['b','c','d'] ]  
|  E|  a3|  79| 79| a3|[a3, 79]| [ a3 -> ['a','d'], 79 -> ['b','c'] ]
|  F|null|null| 38| 38|    [38]| [ 38 -> ['c','d'] ]
+---+----+----+---+---+--------+
```

And, actually, what I really want is a nicely readable report, like:

```
D
  a3 roles: a
  36 roles: b, c, d
E
  a3 roles: a, d
  79 roles: b, c
F
  38 roles: c, d
```

I'm using PySpark 3.

Any suggestions? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, first, unpivot the dataframe then using some groupby you can construct the map column you want.

Input dataframe:

```
data = [
    ("D", "a3", "36", "36", "36", ["a3", "36"]),
    ("E", "a3", "79", "79", "a3", ["a3", "79"]),
    ("F", None, None, "38", "38", ["38"]),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "a", "b", "c", "d", "ppl"])
```

Using [`stack`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#stack) function to unpivot and `map_from_entries` after grouping:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.selectExpr(
    "id",
    "stack(4, 'a', a, 'b', b, 'c', c, 'd', d) as (role, person)"
).filter(
    "person is not null"
).groupBy("id", "person").agg(
    F.collect_list("role").alias("roles")
).groupBy("id").agg(
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col("person"), F.col("roles")))
    ).alias("pplmap")
)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+---+----------------------------+
#|id |pplmap                      |
#+---+----------------------------+
#|F  |{38 -> [c, d]}              |
#|E  |{79 -> [b, c], a3 -> [a, d]}|
#|D  |{a3 -> [a], 36 -> [b, c, d]}|
#+---+----------------------------+
```

If you want to dynamically generate the stack expression (in case you have many role columns), you can see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69884416/1386551).

Comment: This is wonderful. You're a genius! I'd ask, What about the formatted report? but I'd feel too much like _[he had a hat](https://forward.com/schmooze/421730/the-10-best-most-classic-jewish-jokes/#:~:text=8.%20The%20grandparent,had%20a%20hat.%E2%80%9D)_

Answer (score 1):

Set-up:

```py
import pandas as pd     
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'rec': list('DEF'),
    'a': ['a3', 'a3', None],
    'b': [36, 79, None],
    'c': [36, 79, 38],
    'd': [36, 55, 38]
})
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Then [melt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe) the DataFrame accordingly, group by values and aggregate by keys:

```
cols_to_melt = list('abcd')
res = df.withColumn(
    "tmp",
    explode(array(
        [struct(lit(c).alias('key'), col(c).alias('val'))
        for c in cols_to_melt]))) \
    .select('rec', col('tmp.key'), col('tmp.val')) \
    .dropna() \
    .groupby(['rec', 'val']) \
    .agg(collect_list('key').alias('keys')) \
    .groupby('rec') \
    .agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct("val","keys"))).alias('maps'))
res.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|rec|maps                                          |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|F  |{38 -> [c, d], NaN -> [b]}                    |
|E  |{79 -> [c], 79.0 -> [b], a3 -> [a], 55 -> [d]}|
|D  |{36.0 -> [b], a3 -> [a], 36 -> [c, d]}        |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
```

To get your report you just need to iterated through the collected data:

```py
for row in res.collect():
  print(row.rec)
  print('\n'.join(f"  {k} roles: {', '.join(v)}" for k, v in row.maps.items()))
```

Then your final report should look like:

```
F
  38 roles: c, d
  NaN roles: b
E
  55 roles: d
  79 roles: c
  a3 roles: a
  79.0 roles: b
D
  36.0 roles: b
  a3 roles: a
  36 roles: c, d
```

One issue that I did not deal with here is that one of your columns contains both numeric and string values which is not possible in spark.

If you are converting a pandas DataFrame to a spark DataFrame (like I do in my example) you should pass an explicit [schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888188/pyspark-type-error-on-reading-a-pandas-dataframe).

If you are reading from CSV files you might not have to - the type will be automatically inferred as `String`.

However, in that case, in order to group the columns where some have values like `38` and others `"38"` you should make sure all relevant numeric columns are also converted to `String`.

So, in any case it is better to use a schema to ensure you get exactly the types that you need in your DataFrame.